# IOS image sizes for asset catalogs

Tags: interface-builder, resolution, asset-catalog

I am really confused about the required image sizes to be used with interface builder. I am using an asset catalog and there are spaces for 1x, 2x and 3x images.

For a full screen texture for the iPhone 6 plus. I am setting the size to 1242 x 2208 and naming it myimage@3x.jpg and placing in the 3x slot in the asset catalog.

The same image for the iPhone 6 I am setting to 1334 x 750, naming it myimage@2x.jpg and placing it in the 2x slot in the asset catalog.

I then set my UIImage in interface builder to be myimage. I understand xcode will now automatically display the 3@x image on the iPhone 6 plus and the @2x on the iPhone 6. I assume the 1x slot is for non retina phones (3gs, 4, etc)

My question is how do I get a 1136 x 640 image to be displayed on the iPhone 5s. Will the 5s continue to use the 1334 x 720 image thats for the iPhone 6 or can I somehow create a 1136 x 640 the will be automatically selected by xcode when the app is running on an iPhone 5s.